# Bootstrap 3 nav-stacked collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing my friends website and I'm in the process of making the navigation menu. I used nav-pills with nav-stacked inside of a div called navigation that is like it's container.

HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
<a href="./" id="logo">Logo</a>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="padding-top:50px;">
  <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>           Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Exile Support <small>Coming Soon</small></a></li>
  <li class="nav-header disabled"><a href="#">Market</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> Server Ranks</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Shop</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation{
min-width: 200px;
margin: 0;
min-height: 800px;
float: left;
display: block;
clear: both;
font-size: 10px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(227,227,227,1) 0px,rgba(227,227,227,0) 40px),-webkit-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,.12),rgba(0,0,0,.08) 1px,rgba(0,0,0,.08) 1px,transparent 30px,transparent 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(227,227,227,1) 0px,rgba(227,227,227,0) 40px),-moz-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,.12),rgba(0,0,0,.08) 1px,rgba(0,0,0,.08) 1px,transparent 30px,transparent 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(227,227,227,1) 0px,rgba(227,227,227,0) 40px),-webkit-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,.12),rgba(0,0,0,.08) 1px,rgba(0,0,0,.08) 1px,transparent 30px,transparent 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(227,227,227,1) 0px,rgba(227,227,227,0) 40px),-o-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,.12),rgba(0,0,0,.08) 1px,rgba(0,0,0,.08) 1px,transparent 30px,transparent 100%);
}

#navigation .nav-pills > li.active > a,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover, 
.nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
background: #6E28C9;
margin-left: 10px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
color: #b3c7e4;
}

#navigation .nav-pills > li > a {
border-radius: 0;
}
#navigation .nav-pills > li > a:hover{
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 5px #5f5f5f;
}

#navigation .nav > li > a {
padding: 10px 20px 20px;
}

#navigation .nav > li > a small{
color: #999999;
font-size: 7.7px;
float: right;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navigation .nav > li.disabled.nav-header > a {
cursor: default;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navigation .nav > li:nth-child(4) > a:hover {
box-shadow: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
#navigation .nav{
    float: left;
}
}
```

I attempted to use @media to make the navigation push up top, but it didn't work out. So here's what I'm trying to do:

The navigation works. It just isn't responsive. I would like it to collapse like the navbar and jump to the top of the page on mobile devices instead of staying off to the side. Nothing I'm doing is working out and everything I copy of the internet isn't what I need. I'm trying to have it collapse, but instead it just sticks to the side when I shrink the window and all the content is pushed below it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9XrJp/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood you correctly, but try to modify your minimum height and minimum width settings in your css - It responded to changes in the jsfiddle viewport with

```
min-width: 50px
min-height: 200px
```